# Média Hibernate/SQL de uma tabela com múltiplo relacionamentos

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistência

Tenho as seguintes tabelas

**TABELA1** 
*id 

valor 

tabela2*

**TABELA2** 
*id 

tabela3*

**TABELA3** 
*id*

E com isso, gostaria de fazer uma média da TABELA 1, com o WHERE nos parametros TABELA 3 com Hibernate/persistence, sendo que minhas tabelas são objetos.

Seria assim:
SELECT AVG(valor) FROM tabela1 WHERE tabela1.tabela2.tabela3.id = N ?

Comment: Esses relacionamentos são todos `@OneToOne` ou `@ManyToOne`?

Comment: Acho que isto que você quer fazer está certo. Já tentou isso? Se sim, aconteceu algum erro?

Comment: Está relacionado com ManyToOne

Comment: A última tabela é tabela **3** né? ._.

Comment: Sua pergunta é como fazer isso com uma consulta hibernate ou jpa(hql, criteria, Query, etc....)?

Comment: @IgorVenturelli Sim

Comment: @BrunoSpy se fosse um SQL normal, eu usaria os Inner Joins, e até hoje não tive necessidade de fazer um select referente a uma terceira tabela e gostaria de saber como que é feita, se colocaria inner join, ou só usando referencia do objeto normal, como o do Select simples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que:

- As tabelas estão corretamente mapeadas em classes;
- As classes se chamam, respectivamente, `Tabela1`, `Tabela2` e `Tabela3`;
- Os atributos das classes se chamam `tabela2` e `tabela3`:

Então você pode fazer:

```
select avg(t.valor) from Tabela1 t where t.tabela2.tabela3.id = {valor}
```

Comment: Estarei testando :)

Comment: this.entityManager.createQuery("SELECT AVG(t.valor) FROM Tabela1 t WHERE t.tabela2.tabela3 = :tabela3_id").setParameter("tabela3_id", variavel).getSingleResult();